# NameError: name 'token' is not defined microsoftgraph.client

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I can't seem to set `token` in the code below. Does anyone know what I am missing here? https://pypi.org/project/microsoftgraph-python/#description

**Python Code:**

```
from microsoftgraph.client import Client
client = Client('client_id', 'client_pass', account_type='by defect common', office365=True)

token = client.set_token(token)

me = client.get_me()
events = client.get_me_events()

print(events)

print(me)
```

**Result:**

```
token = client.set_token(token)
NameError: name 'token' is not defined
```

Comment: You haven't initialized `token` before `token = client.set_token(token)`, so the interpreter does not recognize the `token` inside the parentheses

Comment: how does one initialize `token`?

Comment: `token` is just an arbitrary variable inside your code. You need to get the token from somewhere depending on what your code does.

Comment: Were you able to find how to define the token? I'm getting the same issue

Answer (score 0):

`token = client.set_token(token)`

The right-hand side of the assignment is evaluated first.  `token` is not defined anywhere else in the code, and so it is an undefined name.